# counting processes, stationary and independent increments

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I know that Poisson process has stationary and independent increments. Are there any other known discrete processes with these two properties?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Any "sum process" where the value at a time t is given by adding a random variable to the value at an earlier time works. Most important is probably the "wiener process" which has gaussian increments.

Comment: Thank you, My main point was about discrete processes like Geometric process which I do not know if it has stationary increments and independent increments. (I added "discrete" to the question).

Comment: No, a geometric process does not have stationary increments. Also I think if you really only consider counting processes with continuous time and the value being non-negative whole numbers, then the poison process is the only  process where the increments are independent and only depend on the difference of times and not time itself.

Comment: The answer changes if you relax any of the conditions. Allow negative values, or allow non-integer values, or allow correlation between increments, or allow time-dependence, or make time discrete...